# Add C# X509Certificate2 to X509Store with AllowPlaintextExport flag?

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, x509certificate2, cng

When I import a certificate into a store using CertUtil, e.g., `certutil -f -v -user -privatekey -importPFX my mycert.p12`, and then read it in in C#, I see that its export policy is `AllowExport | AllowPlaintextExport`.

However, when importing the same certificate to the same store using the `X509Store.Add()` method and then read it back in, the export policy is only `AllowExport`; I use the `X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable` flag when importing the certificate to the store, e.g.,:

```
...
X509Certificate2Collection x509cert2Collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
x509cert2Collection.Import(myp12bytes, passwd, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
foreach (X509Certificate2 x509cert2 in x509cert2Collection) {
    X509Store myStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    myStore.Add(x509cert2);                          
    myStore.Close();
}
...
```

My question is: is there a way to add a X509Certificate2 to the X509Store in C# so that the certificate's export policy includes both `AllowExport` and `AllowPlaintextExport`?  X509KeyStorageFlags does not seem to define the `AllowPlaintextExport` flag; only the `CngExportPolicies` does.

FYI, I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.1 as the target.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a business case to utilize this flag?

Comment: I'm exporting the cng keys to create BouncyCastle keys as described, e.g., [here](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/Import-an-ECDSA-public-key-from-CngKey-to-BouncyCastle-td4658365.html).  When doing so with a cert imported with certutil, it works,but an exception is raised when doing the same with a cert added with C# API.